# Setup of Doctrine CLI not quite working

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-1.2

Still struggling to get doctrine working properly on my system. I have a yaml file that describes the structure of my database and tables. (I am following the tutorial on zendcast). I have my doctrine script file as

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
include('doctrine.php');
```

and the doctrine.php file contains

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
|| define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') :       'development'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
APPLICATION_ENV,
APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap('doctrine');
$config = $application->getOption('doctrine');

$cli = new Doctrine_Cli($config);
$cli->run($_SERVER['argv']);
```

My application.ini excerpt is

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Doctrine_"

;--
;Database
;--
doctrine.dsn = "mysql://root:softna@localhost/gepm2"
doctrine.data_fixtures_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/data/fixtures"
doctrine.sql_path           = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/data/sql"
doctrine.migrations_path    = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/migrations"
doctrine.yaml_schema_path   = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/schema.yml"
doctrine.models_path        = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Gepm/Model"
```

When I run:

```
D:\www\gepm2\application\scripts>php doctrine build-all-reload
```

I get the ff feedback:

```
D:\www\gepm2\application\scripts>php doctrine build-all-reload
build-all-reload - Are you sure you wish to drop your databases? (y/n) y
build-all-reload - Successfully dropped database for connection named 'doctrine'
build-all-reload - Successfully created database for connection named 'doctrine'
build-all-reload - Created tables successfully
build-all-reload - Data was successfully loaded
```

However when I check mysql only the database is created no tables are generated. I have struggled with this for a whole day. Someone help.

---

### EDIT

---

All right I got it working now.But to be honest with you the only changes I made to the code was to
1. set the time zone,
2. remove the underscore from the end of the utoloaderNamespaces[] value so utoloaderNamespaces[] = "Doctrine_" became autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Doctrine" and
3. move the doctrine database declarations to the bottom of the [production] section in the applications.ini

I am so far behind on schedule with what I am working on that I cannot mess about with these changes to see which one or why it worked. I will do say later when I have some down time. In the meantime a more knowledgeable geek may be able to explain why it may have worked. cheers.

Comment: i did had the same issue , with no luck

Comment: it didn't work from ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 0):

The way doctrine creates tables in the db is by loading the models and reading the definitions within each of these models. If the CLI is not able to load the models then the table creation will fail. Unfortunately the CLI task does not report this.

Further I would advise you to check other CLI tasks such as generate-migrations-diff and migrate. I have had issues with these in the past and have resolved them successfully.